# How can I disable work item creation at the end of a failed Team Foundation Build?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I'm using Team Foundation Build but we aren't yet using TFS for problem tracking, so I would like to disable the work item creation on a failed build. Is there any way to do this? I tried commenting out the work item info in the TFSBuild.proj file for the build type but that didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try adding this inside the PropertyGroup in your TFSBuild.proj:

```
<SkipWorkItemCreation>true</SkipWorkItemCreation>
```

---

If you are curious as to how this works, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets contians the following:

```
  <Target Name="CoreCreateWorkItem"
          Condition=" '$(SkipWorkItemCreation)'!='true' and '$(IsDesktopBuild)'!='true' "
          DependsOnTargets="$(CoreCreateWorkItemDependsOn)">

    <PropertyGroup>
      <WorkItemTitle>$(WorkItemTitle) $(BuildNumber)</WorkItemTitle>
      <BuildLogText>$(BuildlogText) &lt;a href='file:///$(DropLocation)\$(BuildNumber)\BuildLog.txt'&gt;$(DropLocation)\$(BuildNumber)\BuildLog.txt&lt;/a &gt;.</BuildLogText>
      <ErrorWarningLogText Condition="!Exists('$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\ErrorsWarningsLog.txt')"></ErrorWarningLogText>
      <ErrorWarningLogText Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\ErrorsWarningsLog.txt')">$(ErrorWarningLogText) &lt;a href='file:///$(DropLocation)\$(BuildNumber)\ErrorsWarningsLog.txt'&gt;$(DropLocation)\$(BuildNumber)\ErrorsWarningsLog.txt&lt;/a &gt;.</ErrorWarningLogText>
      <WorkItemDescription>$(DescriptionText) %3CBR%2F%3E $(BuildlogText) %3CBR%2F%3E $(ErrorWarningLogText)</WorkItemDescription>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <CreateNewWorkItem
          TeamFoundationServerUrl="$(TeamFoundationServerUrl)"
          BuildUri="$(BuildUri)"
          BuildNumber="$(BuildNumber)"
          Description="$(WorkItemDescription)"
          TeamProject="$(TeamProject)"
          Title="$(WorkItemTitle)"
          WorkItemFieldValues="$(WorkItemFieldValues)"
          WorkItemType="$(WorkItemType)"
          ContinueOnError="true" />

  </Target>
```

You can override any of this functionality in your own build script, but Microsoft provide the handy SkipWorkItemCreation condition at the top, which you can use to cancel execution of the whole target.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tfs2010 or above you can do this in the build definition itself.

In the **Process tab** of Build Definition set the `Create Work Item on failure` property to `false` (under the Advanced section)